# What is the difference between Thread.Sleep() and selenium.setSpeed("2000")?

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

What is the difference between `Thread.Sleep()` and `selenium.setSpeed("2000")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setSpeed` : Set execution speed (i.e., set the millisecond length of a delay which will follow each selenium operation). By default, there is no such delay, i.e., the delay is 0 milliseconds.

`Thread.sleep` : It causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period.

So the main difference between them is `setSpeed` sets a speed while will apply delay time before every selenium operation takes place. But one `thread.sleep()` will set up wait only for once. So, if we have 3 selenium operations written like below:

```
Opeartion 1
Opeartion 2
Opeartion 3
```

and we want to set a delay time 2000 for each of these, defining `setSpeed()` method once will accomplish the task something like below:

```
selenium.setSpeed("2000");
Opeartion 1
Opeartion 2
Opeartion 3
```

But if we use `Thread.sleep()`, it will be something like below:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
Opeartion 1
Thread.sleep(2000);
Opeartion 2
Thread.sleep(2000);
Opeartion 3
```

Comment: in the statement "selenium.setSpeed("2000")", what is selenium? Is it an inbuilt command or object of any class?

Comment: @MaruthiSrinivas It's a selenium IDE method and also available in Selenium RC bindings.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep()` will stop the current (java) thread for the specified amount of time. It's done only once.

`Selenium.setSpeed()` will stop the execution for the specified amount of time for **every** selenium command. It is useful for demonstration purpose (you will see thing moving in your browser) or if you are using a slow web application (there are better technique to handle slow applications but that's off topic.)